# Trying to implement a follow up date

Tags: 2010, date-time

We have a calendar in sharepoint 2010 Foundation that we have added some extra columns and workflows but I am trying to impliment a followup date.

At the moment all we have done is created a calculated column and added 14 days to it, this then is used in the workflow to pause for 14 days, but I also want the option when the user is entering the details into the calendar to add a specific date for follow up or default to end time + 14 days.

I thought that I would be able to add a date and time column and calculate the default value, but it appears that you can only use Today in the calculate field for a date and time column and I need to use the "end time" column + 14 days.

I've searched and tried to think of another way to do this and would appreciate any suggestions

Comment: `=[EndTimeColumnName]+14` this should work... You can use your existing columns in the list, not necessary to be [Today]..

Comment: Hi, I have tried that but I get the following error. It works OK in a calculated column, but when the column is a date a time column and I try to use the Calculated value for the default value I get  Error 
The formula contains reference(s) to field(s). 
Learn more about the syntax for formulas. 

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: 1703054f-cce8-4e12-bb8c-ce1539ca6132

Answer (score 0):

I realised that you can't calculate on a field until the record is saved so therefor you can't have a default value based on a column on the current record.

I suppose you could probably do it with javascript but we are trying to keep away from as many hacks as possible.